# repaint causes component overflow

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I hope that I used the question function correctly this time. I have been confused by a question from yesterday to now. I used Google search to ask my java teacher and did not solve my problem.

When I use `repaint`, the child components in the shaped `JPanel` will exceed their display area. As in the following figures,

This is the effect I want
[image: This is the effect I want]

But when I use repaint somethings changes.
[image: But when I use repaint somethings changes.]

The button doesn’t seem right at first.
[image: The button doesn’t seem right at first.]

But sometimes the button will return to normal
[image: But sometimes the button will return to normal]

these are my code. I use repaint because the information I checked tells me that I can use it. Repaint to achieve animation effects.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

class GPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.clip(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), getWidth(), getHeight()));
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}

public class MainComponentOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        // This is a panel with a shape
        GPanel panel = new GPanel();

        // This one is the effect I am looking for, the rectangle is displayed in the Panel.
        //panel.add(new Normal());
        // The following two will have problems, the rectangle will be displayed outside the Panel
        //panel.add(new Problem1());
        panel.add(new Problem2());

        //panel.add(new JButton("This will also cause problems, but it may also display properly when I resize the window."));

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Normal extends JPanel {

    public Normal() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}

class Problem1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public Problem1() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(16, this);
        timer.start();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}

class Problem2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public Problem2() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(16, this);
        timer.start();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setBackground(new Color((float) Math.random(), (float)Math.random(), (float)Math.random()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: `public class Main {` (sigh..) How about a more descriptive name like `public class MainComponentOverflow {`? I keep a single package for working on SO code, and there are a lot of people wanting to call their code `Main`! Be creative, be descriptive and make things easier for me. (Please.)

Comment: I will be a creative programmer.Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: `paintComponent` is responsible for drawing the component itself, not the children.  The children are handled by [paintChildren](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintChildren%28java.awt.Graphics%29).  You’ll want to override both methods.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing - The Paint Methods](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks) for all the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the frame is painted first, the clip will be set in `GPanel`, and then the children will be painted in `Problem1` with the same clip, so it will work.

However, when you repaint `Problem1`, `GPanel` will not be repainted first, so the clip isn’t set, and there is no clip to restrict `Problem1`.

If instead of repainting `Problem1` you repaint the parent, `GPanel`, it will resolve your problem.

Another solution would be to put the clip in `Problem1` too.

Note that you can replace your `RoundRect2D` with an `Ellipse2D`, as you use it to paint an ellipse.